# How to determine what caused an update to the database

Tags: vba, events, ms-access

I have a question regrading how to determine where a record update came from...

I have an Access 2010 database with multiple tables and multiple forms.  All forms have VBA code behind them.  Many of the VBA subs and functions insert, update or delete records.  I use the afterupdate, afterinsert and afterdelete events to write details of changes made to an audit table.  The audit table stores details such as when the change was made, who by and what was changed (action type, table, record id etc.).

**As I mentioned, many different subs / functions make changes to the database.  What I want to know is, how can I find out which sub / function module initiated the database change request?**

At present I have added a global string variable to each sub / function module that updates the database and called a function within the setfield of a crearecord within the afterupdate / afterdelete / afterinsert event to read the variable and so put it on the audit table record.  This is a solution but not a great one.  **Anybody got any better ideas?**

In web development, I could read the HTTP server variables to see how the user got to the current page (referrer and referrer_URL).  Is there something hidden away in one of the objects within Access that would give me something similar?

Comment: I think using your audit table is a good idea. It sounds like you need a public Logging  function used in every sub routine that will append a record to the audit table with the necessary information. This can be tedious, but logging can be a very valuable tool. I'm not aware of another route to take to achieve your results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (hoping?  praying??) that this all gets done in one single module.  In other words, you're passing all this info as a variable to a public Function.  If not, you should.  And while you're passing the variables, just pass the function name to it along with all the other data.

For instance, you would have a public Function in a Module like this:

```
Public Function ChangeLog(chgDate As Date, strByWhom As String, etc..., strModName as String)
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'Put some code here to write all the variables into fields in your ChangeLog table

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "CalendarFor()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Then you just pass all the variables into it like (assume a form named MyForm and this is placed in the After Update event):

```
Call ChangeLog(Now(), CurrUser, etc..., "MyForm - AfterUpdate")
```

Obviously this is "air code", but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: I think I have accidentally misled you.  The afterinsert etc events I have are at table level, not form level.  What I want to know is  thus is it somehow possible to determine which module fired the table insert / delete / update that fired the subsequent corresponding afterinsert / afterdelete / afterupdate table level event?

Comment: Ahhh.  I don't know if that's possible, you may have to change it to be at the form level using the method above.  There's no way I know of that you can tell the table which module was firing it.